# How to write common attribute in one place of Extjs Button Menu

Tags: extjs

I have buttons and menu. In menu there are few thing common. How to write this in common place so my code is optimised. 
In my code `iconCls` is same for both the button. similarly many things will come so how to write as default.

My code :

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

new Ext.panel.Panel({
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'A Panel',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    tools: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Foo',
        iconCls:'Item',
        menu: {
            items: [{
                text: 'Item 1',
                iconCls:'Item',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('Item 1');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Item 2',
                iconCls:'Item',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('Item 2');
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the defaults property.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

new Ext.panel.Panel({
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'A Panel',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    tools: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Foo',
        iconCls:'Item',
        menu: {
            defaults: {
                iconCls: 'Item'
            },
            items: [{
                text: 'Item 1',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('Item 1');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Item 2',
                handler: function() {
                    console.log('Item 2');
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
});
});
```